# How can I view the option "General User Permission"?

Tags: permissions

I can see an option as "General User Permission", in which I need to change some settings in order to enable some feature. But I couldn't able to see any Screens/options anywhere in my Settings under this name.

Can someone please help me to identify this option "General User Permission" in Salesforce?
Is it under Profile/Permission Set/User?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it under `Profile` ->

[image]

To display this, ensure that this option is disabled

```
Setup->Customize->User Interface->Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface
```

[image]

Comment: Great, please mark it as the answer so the question can be closed and for other's benefit.